# Conjecture: Finitely many points where gravitational field due to N masses vanishes

Tags: real-analysis, mp.mathematical-physics, classical-mechanics

Given a configuration $C$ of $N$ distinct fixed points of equal mass in the plane (eventually in space), let $f_C(N)$ denote the number of points $P$ for which the gravitational field at $P$ vanishes. The gravitational force is Newtonian, i.e $1/r^2$.

For example $f_C(2)=1$ for all $C$ and for a configuration $C$ of $3$ unequally spaced collinear points, $f_C(3)=2$.

Conjecture: $f_C(N)$ is always finite and nonzero.

Is this problem known? Can we establish an upper bound on $f_C(N)$?

Comment: one question is: what is the power law that you have in mind? It's like gravity in plane can mean both $g\sim \frac{1}{r^2}$ or $g\sim \frac{1}{r}$. In any event, the definining equations for the zero gravity locus are $d$ polynomials and at least generically there are finitely many points (in fact, for transversal case you can compute the number of points from Bezout theorem). Also could you specify what is your base field: $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$?

Comment: There is a trivial counterexample with two points and the line/plane of points that are equidistant from them. More generally, one expects the zero points to lie on surfaces of codimension 1. @AknazarKazhymurat, the zero points do satisfy a polynomial, but it is a polynomial in two or three variables, so it does not necessarily have finitely many zeros.

Comment: I think, notation $f(N)$ is misleading: this function depends not on $N$ only, but on configuration.

Comment: @NoahStephens-Dawidowitz the field is vector, so we have three polynomial equations in three variables, in general this should define a discrete set.

Comment: @NoahStephens-Davidowitz I'm afraid I don't understand your counterexample. If the masses are located at $(\pm 1,0)$, then the gravitational field at $(0,1)$ is a nonzero vector directed towards the origin, isn't it?

Comment: In general $f$ is not a function of $N$. This is because for the same value of $N$, $f(N)$ may be multiple-valued (due to the geometry, as mentioned in an earlier comment).

Comment: @Wojowu  That is correct.   Only the force perpendicular to the line vanishes.

Comment: Yes, sorry, my previous comment was dumb.

Comment: @FedorPetrov: ok I changed the notation, not that it really matters.

Comment: Crossposted to [math](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2457458/points-where-the-gravitational-field-of-n-masses-vanishes#comment5085342_2457458) and [physics](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/361162/number-of-points-where-gravitational-field-due-to-n-point-masses-vanishes).

Answer (score 15):

Since you are talking about gravitation (rather than electrostatics) I assume
that all charges are positive. (With charges of different sign it is easy to arrange a whole curve of equilibrium points).

It is certainly non-zero if the number of points is at least 2. (From very general consideration it must be at least $N-1$ if you count multiplicitis properly. Without counting multiplicities it can be $1$ for any $N$).

But an exact upper estimate is not known. J. C. Maxwell conjectured that is is 
at most $(N-1)^2$, but this is wide open. Even finiteness is not known. I know only  computer-assisted proof for
$N=3$ but I have not checked it. If one assumes finiteness, then there are
upper estimates but they are much worse than expected.

Reference: http://www.math.purdue.edu/~eremenko/dvi/equil2.pdf

Comment: "Since you are talking about gravitation (rather than electrostatics) I assume that all charges are positive": isn't this statement a little shady? Given that gravitational forces are always attractive?

Comment: @KonstantinosKanakoglou Depends on your definition of positive and the scalar potential.

Comment: @KonstantinosKanakoglou At its root, the question is just about Newtonian $r^{-2}$ potential fields; aside from charge, there's no real difference between gravity and EM fields in that regard.

Comment: @AlexandreEremenko: Why is it obvious that the number of points is nonzero? For example even with $N=3$, if the configuration does not consist of 3 collinear points or an equilateral triangle, the existence of a point $P$ where the field vanishes is not obvious.

Comment: @JoshuaBenabou How about the following? If you consider a sufficiently large ball $B$ which contains all the points in its interior, it is clear that the gravitational field $F$ is continuous on $B$ and pointing into $B$ everywhere on its surface. Then for a sufficiently small $\varepsilon$, $x+\varepsilon F(x)$ is in $B$ for all $x\in B$. As an endomorphism of a convex compact subset, it has a fixpoint (where $F$ has to be $0$) by the Schauder fixpoint theorem.

Comment: @KlausDraeger: This is what I referred to as "general considerations" in my answer: arguments which use very little of the nature of the potential.